# How to deeply compare non-serializable objects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serialization

Let's say we have two cursor files, which are loaded into c# objects:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Resource.file1))
    _cursor1 = new System.Windows.Input.Cursor(ms);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Resource.file2))
    _cursor2 = new System.Windows.Input.Cursor(ms);
```

There are reasons I'd like to compare these objects (e.g. assume that `file1` can be a copy of `file2` and I'd like to detect it). I've a method which tries to deserialize objects to byte arrays, in order to finally compare such arrays:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this object obj)
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the usage throws serialization error:

```
var equal = _cursor1.ToByteArray().SequenceEqual(_cursor2.ToByteArray());
```

> Additional information: Type 'System.Windows.Input.Cursor' in Assembly
>   'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

What is the way to compare such objects?

Comment: Use a different serializer?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to compare the memory streams to check if they are equal or not.

Even more you can select what you want to compare and what not. If you try to compare Cursor objects maybe they have internal data that makes them different even if the have the same shape.

I think that you know how to compare `MemoryStreams`, otherwise just say it.

**EDIT**: Ok. As far as I see the thing that's your only option. After decompiling the cursor class almost all the work is done with unmanaged code so you won't have access to it.

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", BestFitMapping=false, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint="LoadImage", ExactSpelling=false, SetLastError=true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar=true)]
        internal static extern NativeMethods.CursorHandle LoadImageCursor(IntPtr hinst, string stName, int nType, int cxDesired, int cyDesired, int nFlags);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I have no access to these streams. I have access to the cursor objects only.

Comment: I don't see how the provided P/Invoke is relevant?

Comment: @aevitas: the cursor class does not have any state inside as everything is done with the provided pinvoke so it will be difficult to get internals even using reflection.

Comment: I know that cursor is internally loaded by unmanaged code but finally that object is stored somewhere in the memory. Isn't there any way to extract these bytes from the memory block? If I think correctly, in c++ you could possibly copy sizeof bytes from cursor pointers using memcpy, iterate over them and compare corresponding bytes.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko: all you have available is a safehandle. I don't know how you can find the memory address of the object pointed by that safehandle. Anyway there is no guarantee that two cursors with the same image will have identical memory bytes as they can store other things apart from the image. You would need to know where in the memory stream is the image stored.